# Bootstrap same height cards within cols

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

With Bootstrap 3.3.6 I want to make 3 cards.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Some dummy text here</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Some dummy text here</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Some dummy text here</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Now that the Dummy text is not the same length, the cards will not be the same height.

I found a trick using flexbox here: [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height), but this will be working on the immediate children of the .row not the .card

Another thing, even if the cards will be the same height, the buttons will not be on the same line as they will follow the the text.

Answer (score 2):

There is no CSS property that can align items in **different elements** to one another...not even in flexbox.

You **could** always make the button be at the bottom though...that's just a matter of making the card 100% height of the equal height columns.

```css
.row.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.row.flex .col-md-4 {
  float:none;
  width: 33.3333%;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  font: 100%;
  flex:1;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row flex">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Some dummy text here</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, dolor!</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, dolor!</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Some dummy text here</p>
      <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, this doesn't work in the Snippet but here's a Codepen.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/AXxxZJ)

Comment: Sorry for that but everything works well except that the col's won't break as they should to be col-md-12 when resizing the browser and reaching the md breakpoint.

Comment: That's a simple matter of adding `flex-wrap:wrap` to the rows....but the concept is there.

Comment: Well it obviously DOES as it works in the Codepen. If you have a **separate ** question arising from this, then I'd sugegst you ask that in a separate post.

Comment: I've added  flex-wrap: wrap; after display: flex; within .col.flex and tested on Chrome v51 and Firefox v47 and still doesn't work. (on Codepen)

Comment: Again...ask a NEW question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117422/discussion-between-medk-and-paulie-d).

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your `card` div and set your `card` class with the `col-md-4` 
And from that you can put the same height with flexbox like that

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the problem here is that bootstrap col's don't have margins and they are stick to each other and I need the cards to be separated with some 20px spacing.